# Why python interpreter with tensorflow doesnt work with VS code and doesnt give me any errors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, visual-studio-code

I have been trying to install tensorflow on my computer and make it works for 3 days.
I thought I finnally made it work, because of lack of errors, but it looks like it doesnt compiling in VS code.
I used python 3.6, tensorflow 2.3.0, keras 2.4.3.

[Everything works in cmd:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfFEv.png)

[But in VS code It do nothing:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctn1N.png)

It doesnt matter what I write in vs code, it looks the same (tryied even look While True and results were the same)

Comment: have you treid python.exe instead of pythonw.exe? Also please don't post pictures but code instead.

Comment: Sure, next time i will use code.
And I just tryied with python.exe and it works. 
Thanks